# C# Setting custom headers to httpclient gives error as misused header name

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to set custom headers like these

```
x-my-header:somecustomval
content-type:application/vnd.status+json
.
.
.
other headers
```

There are two approaches I tried, using a dictionary of headers

#1

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

foreach (var h in headers)
{
  _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(h.Key.ToString(), h.Value.ToString());
}
```

#2

```
HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage();

foreach (var h in headers)
{
  req.Headers.Add(h.Key.ToString(), h.Value.ToString());
}
```

The error I am getting in both approaches is this:

> Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with
> HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and
> content headers with HttpContent objects.

How do you set the headers for a POST in the HttpClient in C# net core 3.1? Can you not set custom headers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`HttpHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpHeaders.cs,112) method in either of your attempts.

Internally the default `HttpHeaders.Add` will try to validate that you are adding a known HTTP header and will fail if not valid.

Reference [HttpHeaders](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpHeaders.cs,13)

Comment: thanks. tried that with approach #1 and it worked .